# Trying to flip an OpenGL texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to invert the Y values of a texture on OpenGL ES 2.0, and have had no luck after several days of experimentation.  Here's the code in my didRender block (it's a scene kit scene).

```
        let textureCoordinates: [GLfloat] = [
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0]

    let flipVertical: [GLfloat] = [
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0]

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, 0, flipVertical)
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, 0, textureCoordinates)
    glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), 0, 4)
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0)

    glFlush()
```

Is there anything that sticks out to you as wrong? My understanding is that I can flip the texture without having to rewrite to a new texture.  Is that true? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate vertex attribute to do the flip; just replace the `textureCoordinate` array with the values from `flipVertical` (and then delete all of the code related to `flipVertical` - you don't need it).